# adb - unable to connect to <ip-address:port>: No route to host

Tags: networking, router, ping, adb

I was trying to connect my phone with adb over wi-fi (I did tcpip to 5555), but not working since I bought a new router. It works fine when using my other phone as a hotspot. I was trying to ping to my mobile's IP address, but it was showing Destination host unreachable. What do I have to change in my router to make it work? And my router is D-LINK DIR-816 and my devices are connect on 2.4 GHz networks. [Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJmpd.png).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that, it was a router problem
**SSID isolation** and **user isolation** to be precise.
I tuned of both of them and connection is back.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jurlb.png)